# Jquery AJAX responseText returns undefined

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Im trying to upload an image to server using ajax and it worked, now the problem is returning the data from AJAX, it keeps on giving undefined with responText.

```
$('#imageform').submit(function(e){

var formData = new FormData(this);
  var request = $.ajax({
    url: "<? echo site_url('mybazaar/uploadProductImage'); ?>",
    type: "POST",
    data: formData,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (res) {
      var newImage = $(res).filter('‪#ajaximage').html();
      $('#ajax_product_image').append(newImage);
      alert(res.responseText);
    },
    error: function (request, status, error){
      alert(error);
    }
    }).done(function(){

    });
 e.preventDefault();
});
```

PHP file:

```
 public function uploadProductImage(){
    $config['upload_path']          = './images/product_images/';
    $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size']             = 10024;
    $config['max_width']            = 10240;
    $config['max_height']           = 10240;

    $upload_path = 'images/product_images/';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if (!$this->upload->do_upload("product_image_primary")){
        return false;
    }
    else{
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        $this->resize($data['upload_data']['full_path']);
        echo "<div id='ajaximage'><div class='col-md-2'><img src='".base_url().$upload_path.$data['upload_data']['file_name']."'></div></div>";
    }
}
```

However if i only do "alert(res)", the whole page's HTML will be alerted including the text i echoed in "mybazaar/uploadProductImage".

I'm using Jquery 1.9 and CodeIgniter by the way.

Comment: please show us your php file for better help

Comment: What do you expect `res.responseText` to contain?

Comment: Edited with PHP file, res.responseText should contain the data echoed in my PHP file.

Comment: But you just said that `res` contains the data. Note that CodeIgniter most likely places the response inside a page template.

Comment: Yes res contains the data with other page data rendered, but with res.responseText, undefined is returned. I tried filter('#ajaximage').html(), undefined is also returned.

Comment: `res` is the data returned, the `success` handler has the following arguments `success(data, status, xhr)`, the data doesn't have a `responseText` property, which is why it's undefined. Everything that is returned is in `res`, there's no magical way to just get parts of it, you have to look at the HTML you're returning, and get what you want, and without seeing that HTML, there's nothing we can do to help you

Comment: The returned HTML is the echoed HTML in function uploadProductImage with some other page HTMLs. Basically the res.responseText should return anything that is echoed in the ajax call? Correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: This is whats returned:
<div id='ajaximage'><div class='col-md-2'><img src='localhost/ci3/images/product_images/castle102448.png'></div></div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument of `success` callback is the actual data returned from the server in the format specified by content-type header, which is html by default and also in your case. Now that you're getting html back, you don't have to search for div using `filter('‪#ajaximage')`
because that's exactly(div#ajaximage) what you have in `res`, So you can directly append that to your DOM.

```
    success: function (res) {
      $('#ajax_product_image').append(res);
    }
```

I removed `alert(res.responseText)` because `responseText` is not a property defined in the data argument of success callback, it's a property of the actual `XMLHttpRequest` object used to fire the Ajax call. If you still need access to responseText, success callback has 3 arguments `function(data, status, jqXHR). jqXHR(3rd argument basically, you can change the name if you like) will have all the underlying properties of original`XMLHttpRequest` object

Comment: Hi, what if i have multiple divs and i would like to append them in different places in the page? I've used the code before in other projects with no problem $(res).filter('#idtobefiltered').html() but it doesn't seem to work in codeigniter.

Comment: Then enclose that in another div. Now res will be your outer div and your filter will work as usual

Comment: It's enclosed in "ajaximage" div, i'm getting undefined if filtering them.

Comment: No i mean to say enclose your "ajaximage" div in someother div.. Now u should get ur new div in res n doing filter on that should work